# How to add the key values of the dynamically generated array and get their average?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-push

i am generating an array of values in a for each loop. the result looks somewhat like the array values i pasted below. now i want to add the corresponding values of the three iterations and get their average... like for the 0th key i want-   (87+95.2+100)/3 ... like this i want for all the values.. how to do i do it?

This is the code. $items contain these array values which i have pasted below. There are two for each loops and i have to figure out a way to get the averages.

```
foreach ($data['data'] as $k => $v) 
   {
     $items = array();
      foreach ($data['departments'] as $a => $b) 
      {
        $items[] = $v['departments'][$a]['score'];
   }
   }
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($items);
   echo "</pre>";
```

The $items contains the following when i print it out

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 87
    [1] => 88.90000000000001
    [2] => 97.40000000000001
    [3] => 27.4
    [4] => 94.7
    [5] => 91.7
    [6] => 93.90000000000001
    [7] => 100
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 100
    [10] => 94.40000000000001
    [11] => 90
    [12] => 100
    [13] => 78.59999999999999
    [14] => 63.3
    [15] => 97.40000000000001
    [16] => 96.90000000000001
    [17] => 97
)
Array
(
    [0] => 95.2
    [1] => 94.7
    [2] => 95
    [3] => 33.6
    [4] => 94.8
    [5] => 100
    [6] => 92.3
    [7] => 78.59999999999999
    [8] => 92.3
    [9] => 96.40000000000001
    [10] => 92.5
    [11] => 100
    [12] => 96.3
    [13] => 84.09999999999999
    [14] => 63
    [15] => 97.7
    [16] => 94.3
    [17] => 97.09999999999999
)
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 95
    [2] => 91.90000000000001
    [3] => 33.6
    [4] => 98.2
    [5] => 96.3
    [6] => 97.90000000000001
    [7] => 86.7
    [8] => 91.7
    [9] => 96.59999999999999
    [10] => 92.5
    [11] => 100
    [12] => 92.3
    [13] => 83.3
    [14] => 63.6
    [15] => 92.90000000000001
    [16] => 94.40000000000001
    [17] => 98.59999999999999
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$items = array();
foreach ($data['data'] as $k => $v)  {
    foreach ($data['departments'] as $a => $b) {
        $items[$k][] = $v['departments'][$a]['score'];
    }
}

$res = array_map('average', zip($items));

var_dump($res);

function zip($arrays) {
    $zip = [];
    if ($arrays) {
        $count = count(current($arrays));
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            foreach ($arrays as $array) {
                $zip[$i][] = $array[$i];
            }
        }
    }
    return $zip;
}

function average($numbers) {
    return array_sum($numbers) / count($numbers);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. But the three iterations are dynamically generated and are in one single variable and are not seperated into three differennt variables. this is how exactly they are, with out any seperations. I have just shortened the array values. The actual array list is in the main question. Thank you again

Array
(
    [0] => 87
    [1] => 88.90000000000001
    [2] => 97.40000000000001
    [3] => 27.4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 95.2
    [1] => 94.7
    [2] => 95
    [3] => 33.6
)
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 95
    [2] => 91.90000000000001
    [3] => 33.6
)

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by not separated, but why do you put in 3 arrays? Can you show a `var_dump` or `print_r` of the array that contains the values (update your answer)?

Comment: when i do print_r($items), it shows that array output which i was telling you about. this is the output again when i do print_r.

Array ( [0] => 87 [1] => 88.90000000000001 [2] => 97.40000000000001 [3] => 27.4 ) Array ( [0] => 95.2 [1] => 94.7 [2] => 95 [3] => 33.6 ) Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 95 [2] => 91.90000000000001 [3] => 33.6 )

Comment: Ok, could you put an `print_r` of `$data` unless it's a little hard for me to get a result that works.

Comment: Well I don't know what's in `$data` but check the answer's update if it's what you need.

Comment: sorry for the rate reply. I have copied the array in a text file. here is the file link http://theheisenberg.com/arrayfile.txt